# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (when I try to run "python manage.py runserver")

Tags: django, postgis, gdal, geodjango

I installed PostGIS 3.3.
That PostGIS 3.3.2 bundle includes

- PostGIS 3.3.2 w,
- GDAL 3.4.3 (SQLite 3.30.1, OpenJPEG 2.4.0, Expat 2.4.8, FreeXL 1.0.6),
- GEOS 3.11.1,
- Proj 7.2.1,
- pgRouting 3.4.2,
- osm2pgrouting 2.3.8,
- ogr_fdw 1.1.3 spatial foreign data wrapper extension, and
- pgPointcloud 1.2.4, h3-pg 4.0.3.

But when I try to run GeoDjango app, then it stopped with the following error.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal304", "gdal303", "gdal302", "gdal301", "gdal300", "gdal204", "gdal203", "gdal202"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

My system variables show GDAL installed and path set already.

I am trying to setup correctly geodjango with gdal, So kindly expecting help to solve this matter.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved it by myself now,

### Before installing Django,

#### 1. Setup GDAL

run 'OSGeo4W installer'

in CMD (run as administrator)
execute code by code

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
set PYTHON_ROOT=C:\Python310
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal
set PROJ_LIB=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\proj
set PATH=%PATH%;%PYTHON_ROOT%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin
reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"
reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v GDAL_DATA /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%GDAL_DATA%"
reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROJ_LIB /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PROJ_LIB%"
```

#### 2. After installing Django App

Added GeoDjango in 'settings.py' file as follows

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
                   # [...]
                   'django.contrib.gis'
                 ]

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\gdal306.dll"
```

Now it's working properly.